# Is it possible to run Microsoft CRM Reports as a specific user?

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Is it possible to create a custom report using Microsoft CRM 2013 on-premise that will run as another user than the user requesting the report? Would it be possible to store custom credentials in the .rdl file? It doesn't matter whether the solution uses filtered views or Fetch XML.

The goal is to present data for users that is usually out of bounds because of CRM security role limitations.

Comment: You can configure the credentials a report runs under from within SSRS.

Comment: You can query against the base tables instead of the filtered views. It is a bit more work when constructing the query, but the user running the report will not be restricted by the security imposed in the filtered views.